# Dropbox conflict causing Github issues

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

Ugh. So Dropbox has just caused me a couple of issues thanks to it not syncing when it should have. I don't know whether to `merge` or `rebase` or something else. I need some advanced gitfu.

I'm the only developer on the project and the conflict appeared because of switching between my desktop and laptop. Nobody else works with this repo... I could literally wipe the remote repo and start again and it would be fine. (I don't really want to lose the history, but it would be fine from a code POV.)

Running `git push` simply says:

```
To github.com:JCW/kicker-ticketing.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:JCW/kicker-ticketing.git' 
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind 
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

`git status` reveals:

```
On branch master Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, 
and have 6 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I've deleted all the conflicted files (including the ones in `.git/` and manually added all the code changes) -- my local repo is now what should be the remote `origin/master`.

What is the best way, in this particular solo-dev situation, to just push my local repo to become the new remote `origin/master`?

I've read [a few guides on rebase vs merge](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing), but still the obvious solution eludes me.

Next time I will make sure that Dropbox hasn't crashed before continuing to work. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> my local repo is now what should be the remote origin/master

If you are sure in that, to reset the remote state from your local state just run `git push -f`. This is destructive for the remote end, so it is nice if you backup that first.

As a solo developer (and in small teams) I prefer to use `git pull --rebase` to keep the linear history at all times, because it is then easier for me to debug issues like that one.